# "Replace text as you type" gets unchecked automatically

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, autocorrect

I've set up some autocorrect rules in Word, and they work well.

However from time to time "replace text as you type" become unchecked, and I need to go to options and check it again.

I don't have any clue what can cause this behaviour, have anybody else experienced the same?

I have tools generating reports using VBA, checked them but those don't cause this.

[image]

I use MS Office Professional Plus 2013, 32 bit

Comment: Do you install any updates for Office? Maybe some updates change the option.

Comment: It's a company pc and updates are pushed by IT, I don't remember when office update was installed, also don't know how could I check it (it's under Windows 10)

Comment: Or you can check if the IT apply any polices for Word about this setting, open registr editor and go to: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office check 15.0- Word key.

Comment: No, I don't see anything relevant (only values under word are personaltemplates = `%appdata%\microsoft\templates`, defaultformat = (empty) and allownetworklocations = `0x00000001 (1)`)